# Convert string elements to int elements in an array in swift

Tags: swift

I have a string with the following format:

```
var cadenaCoordenadas = """
1,1
1,3
4,1
5,1
1,5
1,6
2,5
0,0
"""
```

What I want is that each line is in the following format (in an array) to manipulate it (with Int data types as I will do operations with the new string):
[1,1]

I have the following code:

```
var arregloEntradas = cadenaCoordenadas.split(separator: "\n")
print("primer Arreglo: ", arregloEntradas)
for i in stride(from: 0, through:arregloEntradas.count - 1, by: 1){
    let arregloEntradasFinal = arregloEntradas[i].split(separator: ",")
    print(arregloEntradasFinal)
}
```

and I get the result of this:

[this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZq8T.png)

as you can see, the array elements are of string type, however I require them to be of Int type:

```
[1,1]
[1,3]
[4,1]
...
```

I hope you can help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: Unrelated: `for i in stride(from: 0, through:arregloEntradas.count - 1, by: 1)` is a bad way of saying `for i in stride(from: 0, to: arregloEntradas.count, by: +1)`, which is a really complicated way of saying `for i in 0..<arregloEntradas.count`, which is a really error prone way of saying `for i in arregloEntradas.indices`. But you don't even need the index, you need the element, so it could just be `for arregloEntradasFinal in arregloEntradas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach using some splitting and mapping:

```
var cadenaCoordenadas = """
1,1
1,3
4,1
5,1
1,5
1,6
2,5
0,0
"""

let arregloEntradasFinal = cadenaCoordenadas.split(separator: "\n")
                           .map { $0.split(separator: ",").compactMap { Int($0) } }
print(arregloEntradasFinal)
```

Output:

> [[1, 1], [1, 3], [4, 1], [5, 1], [1, 5], [1, 6], [2, 5], [0, 0]]

Answer (score 0):

```
var arregloEntradas = cadenaCoordenadas.split(separator: "\n")
print("primer Arreglo: ", arregloEntradas)
for i in stride(from: 0, through:arregloEntradas.count - 1, by: 1){
    let arregloEntradasFinal = arregloEntradas[i].split(separator: ",").map { Int(String($0)) }
    print(arregloEntradasFinal)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're getting in `arregloEntradasFinal` is correct since you're processing the string array. Later, when you want to use `arregloEntradasFinal` again, you should again split a string by a comma separator from `arregloEntradasFinal` and use the individual `Int` value. For example:

```
let index = 0 // You can also loop through the array
let values = arregloEntradasFinal[index].split(separator: ",")
let num1 = Int(values.first ?? 0) // If no value then returns 0
let num2 = Int(values.last ?? 0)  // If no value then returns 0
```

**Note** - this is one of the way without using the  `map` function.